# Excerpt is being added above the content, but it should be after it

Tags: filters, excerpt, the-content

I have this code in my functions.php file to display the excerpt of every post right below the content of every post.

But, for some reason the Excerpt is appearing above the Content when it should be below it.

Can someone show me how to make sure that the Excerpt always show up under the Content...?  Thanks.

```
function after_post_content($content){
if (is_single()) {  
    $content .= the_excerpt();
}
    return $content;
}
add_filter( "the_content", "after_post_content");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are echoing the content of the excerpt, which is being put into the header. Use `get_the_excerpt()` instead:

```
function after_post_content($content){
if (is_single()) {  
    $content .= get_the_excerpt();
}
    return $content;
}
add_filter( "the_content", "after_post_content");
```

Generally, WordPress functions beginning with `the_` will echo the output, while functions starting will `get_the_...` will get the value.